# How to pass a file as a parameter of a procedure

Tags: readfile, ada

I am trying to write a sub procedure to read from a "grocery.txt" file. The format is as follow:
12 7.2 Orange

The first column is an integer, the second is a float. The third one is a String till the end of line. How should I declare the parameter and how can I pass the file variable as a parameter for the sub procedure?

```
 PROCEDURE Read_File(Ada.Text_IO.File_Type => in_Item,
  Item : out Grocery_Item) IS
 BEGIN
  Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(File => In_Item,
     Item => Grocery_Item.Quantity,
        Width => 3);
  Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get(File => In_Item, Item => Grocery_Item.Cost_Per_Item,
     Width => 3);
  Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line(Item => Grocery_Item.Item.Item_Name,
     Last => Grocery_Item.Item.Item_Name_Length);
 END Read_File;
```

I keep getting an error saying I am missing a "," on the PROCEDURE line.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=>` is used only when *calling* procedures or functions.  When you declare them, the syntax is *parameter-name* : [in/out/in out/access] *type*, just like you did with `Item : out Grocery_Item`:

```
procedure Read_File (In_Item : in Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;  -- the "in" keyword is optional
                     Item    : out Grocery_Item) is
...
```

(Just to avoid any possible confusion, `=>` is also used in contexts that have nothing to do with procedures or functions (subprograms).  The point is that when you're using subprograms, you may use `=>` when you call them, but not when you declare them.)

Also, I'm not sure which one is the type and which one is the parameter name: `Item` or `Grocery_Item`?  If `Grocery_Item` is the type, the parameter declaration is fine, but it doesn't make sense to use `Grocery_Item.Quantity`, `Grocery_Item.Item.Item_Name_Length`, etc., in the body, because that's not a place for a type name.  Maybe you want to say `Item.Quantity`, etc.  I can't tell.  If `Item` is actually the type, and `Grocery_Item` will be the name of the parameter, then you need to switch them at the top of the procedure:

```
procedure Read_File (In_Item      : in Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;  -- the "in" keyword is optional
                     Grocery_Item : out Item) is
...
```

But to know for sure, we'd have to see what the declaration of either `type Item` or `type Grocery_Item` is.

Finally, one other thing: why do the first two `Get` calls use a file, but the last `Get_Line` doesn't?  This will cause two reads from your file, and third read will be from the keyboard (probably).  You probably want to add the `File` parameter to the last `Get_Line` too.